# getTimestamp() - Fatal Error when call to a member function

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to convert the following string to datetime:

```
<?php
$t = '2017-12-22T11:46:21.647+00:00';

$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $t);
print_r($date->getTimestamp());
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/t02-convertDateTime.php on line 5
```

Any suggestions why?

Comment: The format you give to `date_create_from_format` needs to match the date-time string you pass in. Yours are completely different.

Comment: `$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.ue', $t);` to match the formatted date/time string that you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute this code:

```
<?php
$t = '2017-12-22T11:46:21.647+00:00';

$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $t);
var_dump($date);
print_r($date->getTimestamp());
```

You get the following output:

```
bool(false) 
FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code:6 Stack trace: #0 /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5): eval() #1 {main} thrown on line number 6
```

Looks like it's an Invalid Date Format. You need to get the right date format.

Also in the manual, there's a comment saying:

> There is no option to specify date format 'c' (e.g. 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00) directly. work around is to use Y-m-d\TH:i:sT

An alternate to this is:

```
<?php
$t = '2017-12-22T11:46:21.647+00:00';

var_dump(date("Y-m-d g:i:s a", strtotime("2017-12-22T11:46:21.647+00:00")));
```

And this gives you:

```
2017-12-22 6:46:21 am
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way that you given the format. Try this one or check [PHP Mannual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$t = '2017-12-22 11:46:21';

$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t);
var_dump($date->getTimestamp());
```